# Подсчет слов в строке

Tags: delphi, алгоритм

Нужно в строке найти количество слов, но нельзя находить их через символ пробел.

```
for i:=1 to length(s) do
 if s[i]=' ' then
```

И так далее. Думаю ясно, что я имею ввиду.

Comment: Не ясно =(

Comment: 0о совсем не ясно. Как их находить, не используя пробел?

Comment: ну возможно слова писатьТипаТакогоВида и тогда искать по большой букве или через_знак_подчеркивания, или знак№заменить№на№что№то№другое, но мне тут и код не нравится, я на делфе не пишу, но вродь тут такое тоже будет не кстати

Comment: пробелы обрезать просто надо, ну у вас и логика, цитата: "если учитель ввел пробел то на одно слово больше считает..."<br>
Ваш вывод гениален - значит надо разделять слова не пробелом... <br><br>О том что просто обрезать пробелы в начале и в конце надо перед обработкой почемуто вам в голову не пришло...

Comment: И не только. Скажите еще, что нужно блоки из пробелов приводить к виду один пробел.

`"Очень длинное      предложение."` -> `"Очень длинное предложение."`

Comment: а флаг readingWord почему не использовать? о_О проще же, быстрее и вообще...

Comment: или же :
for i:=1 to length(s) do
 if (s[i]=' ' and s[i+1]<>' ')
 then ...
и всего то..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот мой вариант функции

```
function kolslov(s:string):integer;
var
c,i:integer;
begin
 s:=trim(s);c:=0;
  for i:=1 to length(s) do if (s[i]=#32)and(s[i-1]<>#32) then inc(c);
result:=c+1;
end;
```

Использовать так

kolslov(s);

Где S строка в которой нужно посчитать количество слов, на выходе число

Comment: спасибо большое)
и слава богу я знаю как обращаться к функциям))

Comment: Да не за что :)
Хотя правильней переписать условие будет так

    if (chr(s[i])>32)and(chr(s[i-1])>32) then inc(c);

Тогда разделителем будет считаться любой не печатный символ и пробел.
Это для того что если хитрый препод решит использовать символ таба или перевода каретки в качестве пробела ;)

Comment: вот знал я chr и даже если бы вы его сразу применили,врядли я бы додумался для чего..вот что значит опытный программёр)

Answer (score 0):

Для поиска слова прекрасно подходит стандартная функция `Pos(<подстрока, т.е. нужное слово>, <строка>)`, результат - целое число, номер символа, с которого начинается слово; если результат равен нулю - такого слова в строке нет. Ниже - код, подсчитывающий количество повторений необходимого слова в строке.

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

Var
  Str, SubStr, MyStr: String;
  Len: Integer;
  Col: LongWord;

begin
  Col:=0;
  Write('Str = ');ReadLn(Str);
  Write('SubStr = ');ReadLn(SubStr);
  MyStr:=Str;

  Len:=Length(SubStr);

  While (Pos(SubStr, Str)<>0) Do
    Begin
      Delete(Str, Pos(SubStr, Str), Len);
      Inc(Col);
    End;

  WriteLn('Col = ', Col);
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Вот код, теперь, вроде, как надо работает:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

Var
  Str, SubStr, MyStr: String;
  i: Integer;
  Col: LongWord;

begin
  Col:=0;
  Write('Str = ');ReadLn(Str);
  MyStr:=Str;

  While (Pos(' ', Str)<>0) Do
    Begin
      i:=Pos(' ', Str);
      Repeat
        Delete(Str, i, 1);
      Until ((Str[i]<>' ') Or (Str=''));
      Inc(Col);
    End;

  If (Str[i]<>'') Then Inc(Col);

  WriteLn('Col = ', Col);
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Comment: Так и спрашивали бы о поиске подстроки или последовательности символов в строке.

Comment: проблема в том что заранее не известно какие слова будут введены..

Comment: так ищите не слово, а символ-разделитель

Comment: вот именно так я и поступил,но вот не задача...Преподаватель в конце строки вводит пробел (я по этому символу определяю) и программа естественно выводит количество слов на 1 больше чем в действительности..

Comment: trim() строки делай, перед обработкой =)

Comment: Тогда проще искать комбинацию из двух символов:

1. пробел
2. alphanumeric

(числа ведь тоже за слова считаются?)

Как только комбинация встретилась - инкрементируем счетчик. 

P.S. на некорректных предложениях (в духе "На дворе трава,на траве дрова." не сработает, т.к. после запятой нет пробела, хотя должен быть, иначе нужно добавлять поддержку знаков препинания).

Comment: большое спасибо,просто новичок я и не знал о такой функции)
думал такая только в SQL есть..